# What is the product of two Haar distributed unitary matrices?

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, geometric-measure-theory, random-matrices, haar-measure

I guess a product of two Haar distributed unitary matrices is also a Haar distributed unitary matrix. Is there a proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the two matrices are chosen independently.

The product of two unitary matrices is unitary.  The distribution is invariant under multiplication on left or right by a unitary matrix.  Use uniqueness of Haar measure...